# React typescript getting data from local json file to highcharts

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript, highcharts

I'm trying to get data from my local json file to a tsx file in my react project.

```
const dataMap = test.map(r => ({
   y: r.value
}));
```

"test" is where the json data is, it is read correctly. But when im trying to iterate to specific data point in the json im getting this error: "Property 'value' does not exist on type '({here is the json data displayed as it is in the json file. Example of one: number: string;".

So basically im trying to get the dataMap variable to highcharts.

EDIT:

So, I managed to do some process. Thank you for your answers.
But Im getting another error. Im getting "Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)
myscriptname.tsx(17, 3): The expected type comes from property 'test' which is declared here on type 'Iinterface'" from the "test" part

```
.then(response => {
    const data: Iinterface[] = [];
    response.data.map(i => {
      data.push({
        test: `${i.test}`
      });
    });
    setChartData(data);
  });
  });
```

I have tried to assign the "test" part in my interface method as number but im getting the above error.

Comment: If you're using `import` to import the JSON file, the imported object usually includes a `default` object nested inside it (even if you do a default import). Maybe try `test.default.map`? Without any more information (json content, how you're importing it, etc), that's the only suggestion I've got

Comment: Hi @Roni, Could you reproduce the problem in some online code editor? You can use this demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-yi81d?file=/demo.jsx to start.